# Appending data when writing from excel sheet to txt document

Tags: excel, python-2.7, csv, xlrd, xlwt

There is a text document called: file.txt with text already on it.

When I go through the excel sheet and write to the text file it erases the original text on it.

**How do I only append the info from the excel sheet while keeping the original text info?**

CODE

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import csv

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(2)

data = []
data.append([sheet.cell_value(row, 0).strip() for row in range(sheet.nrows)])
data.append([sheet.cell_value(row, 1).strip() for row in range(sheet.nrows)])

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

for colidx, col in enumerate(data):
    for rowidx, row in enumerate(col):
        sheet.write(rowidx, colidx, row)    

transposed = zip(*data)
with open('file.txt','wb') as fou:
    writer = csv.writer(fou)
    for row in transposed:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to pass `ab` as a flag to `open()`:

```
transposed = zip(*data)
#                     v
with open('file.txt','ab') as fou:
    writer = csv.writer(fou)
    for row in transposed:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Cheers, mate. Happy coding to you.

Comment: How do I remove all the blank spaces from that file.txt though and saving it as that same file. For example if you run this:                                    input = open('file.txt', 'rb')
output = open('files.txt', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
for row in csv.reader(input):
    if any(field.strip() for field in row):
        writer.writerow(row)
input.close()
output.close()                                                                                         you have to save it as a different document

Comment: Here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061642/removing-blank-spaces-from-a-csv-file-without-creating-a-new-file