# Removing blank spaces from a CSV file without creating a new file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have blank spaces in a csv sheet that I want to get rid of it.

After searching for hours I realized that this is the code for it:

```
input = open('file.txt', 'wb')
output = open('new_file.txt', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(output)
for row in csv.reader(input):
    if any(field.strip() for field in row):
        writer.writerow(row)
input.close()
output.close()
```

**My question is:** How do I remove the blank spaces without having to create a new file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first extract the valid rows and overwrite the file afterwards, provided your file is not too big and thus the rows can fit in the memory entirely

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as inp:
    valid_rows = [row for row in csv.reader(inp) if any(field.strip() for field in row)]

with open('file.txt', 'wb') as out:
    csv.writer(out).writerows(valid_rows)
```